# WHy is my Nohup process dying?

Tags: centos, nohup

What's wrong with this code? Suddenly the `nohup` process dies, without a trace.

```
bin/sh
sleep 5s
cd /home/minecraft/OMC
nohup java -jar -Xms3400M -Xmx3400M -jar paperclip.jar &
```

Comment: Could you give some more context - are you running through ssh? Is nothing being written to nohup.out? If you run the nohup command directly without using a script, does it work? How are you checking that the process is running?

Comment: The first line in that script looks like a typo.

Answer (score 2):

`nohup` itself isn't expected to live long (at least *as* `nohup`):

```
$ nohup sleep 10 < /dev/null > /dev/null &
[1] 773
$ pgrep nohup
$ pgrep sleep
773
$ echo "time passes.."
time passes..
[1]+  Done                    nohup sleep 10 < /dev/null > /dev/null
```

You want instead to look, in your case, for a `java` process.

Comment: So.. Do you mean, it's the Java process dying, which in return kills nohup?

Comment: Hard to say without some logs.